# Why the simplest Shell-Script isn't working?

Tags: terminal, shell, ubuntu-14.04, bash-scripting

I want hide the path in the Terminal and for that reason I typed:

```
export PS1='> '
```

command which I found online with positive result.

I thought to make it to a shell-script in order to not type it every time I open the terminal. So I created a `.sh` file and wrote the following code inside:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PS1='> '
```

When I am running it, typing `bash ./hidepath.sh`, it has no effect.

What I am missing here?

Comment: did you give your script proper permissions - chmod +x /pathToScript ?

Comment: Yes :(. The script was executed but with no effect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run your script in a separate instance of the shell, this is the `#!/bin/sh` part of your script (this has the added side effect of running it in dash, not bash)

If you execute your script **not** with `/path/to/script.sh` but instead with `. /path/to/script.sh` the hashbang will be seen as a comment and ignored, your script will "work".

So basically the script is OK, the call is not.

Answer (score 2):

put

```
PS1='>'
```

into .bashrc in your home directory and logout and login again